# How to Maintain Git Log for repository

Tags: github, github-pages, git-log, git

I have a repository whenever I do commit the log(changelog) file needs to save those by automatic 
can anyone help me, please?

I tried with log comments but it's by manual and writes into the output file.

Comment: What do you want in the log? The commit message? Why not just use git log?

Comment: You use the word "log" in two different meanings. Please specify what exactly do you want? Please show what command(s) have you tried and how they fail.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon when I commit with different users it will automatically save in the log file. So how do I initiate the process?

Comment: @phd My question is how to maintain a log file for my repository

Comment: By logfile you mean the changes made to the repo? Like the contents of reflog?

Comment: @FilipHalaxa Yes

Answer (score 0):

Given those caveats [Keep Git Reflog Indefinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422768/keep-git-reflog-indefinitely) you could make a pre commit hook in your repository, which would just do something like `git reflog > reflog.log; git add reflog.log`. That adds the contents of reflog to `reflog.log` and adds it to index ready to be commited. But keep in mind, that the last commit would not be in `reflog.log`. Your `reflog.log` will always be one commit behind.